# Get all objects that have a certain term

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been looking at the function reference for `wp_user_query`, as well as `wp_get_object_terms` but neither of these seem to do what I need. `wp_user_query` only lets you filter by user meta which isn't helpful. `wp_get_object_terms` lets you pass an object ID and taxonomy and it will return all the terms in that taxonomy that object has.

I need something that's the reverse of that. I have a taxonomy called 'tags' that can be attached to users, and I need to be able to say "get me all the users that have the tags x and y". What should I be using to accomplish this?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get_user-with-taxonomie

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue where I had users with a certain tags/ categories. And I wanted to get users who have the category `signatory`.
I used a combination of

- [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)
- [wp_get_object_terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms)

#### Here is my solution

```
$args = array(
    'blog_id'      => $GLOBALS['blog_id'],
    'role'         => '',
    'role__not_in' => array('administrator', 'bbp_keymaster'),
    'count_total'  => false,
    'fields'       => 'all',
    'who'          => ''
); 
$blogusers = get_users( $args );
```

#### In my div, I output this way

```
<div class="title-tag">Featured Signatory</div>

<?php foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) : ?>
    <?php 
     $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $user->ID, 'user_category' );
     foreach ( $terms as $tax ) {
         if ($tax->slug === 'signatory') {
             echo '<p> ' . $user->display_name . '  </p>';
         }
     }
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will give you all the users which have a `tag` or `category` of your choice.

#### Hope This helps anyone else who has a bunch of user meta that they included in their users profile.